# Create a symbolic link in the main menu

Tags: routes

I have a node "Contact page" and a menu link called "Apply". "Apply" is a menu child of "Contact". Put another way, "Apply" appears on the second level of the main menu under a menu link called "Contact".

When I want to create another "Apply" link which should be a child of the menu link "Programme", "Programme" will receive the "is-active" class as the active menu parent although "Contact" is the original parent and should, ideally, be the active menu trail.

Menu structure:

```
Contact    Programme
  Apply        Apply [symbolic link to Contact > Apply]
```

This is important because there are different sidebars displayed on Programme > Apply versus 
Contact > Apply.

Is there a way to create a symbolic link called "Apply" as a child for the menu link "Programme" that references to "Contact page" and sets "Contact" > "Apply" as the active menu trail?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/4674/7641

Comment: Thanks for this. It is a bit strange that Drupal doesn't have a feature like TYPO3.